# Adding PostGIS raster to QGIS via database manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster

When I attempt to add a PostGIS raster to QGIS I get a GDAL error saying I need to set PGHOST. I have set PGHOST with

```
export PGHOST=localhost
```

but still get the error. How can I resolve this problem?

Using an Ubuntu 14.10 machine with Postgresql 9.4, PostGIS 2.1.3 and QGIS 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it turns out that for GDAL to work with PostGIS raster you need to give all the information to QGIS regarding the connection even if it isn't required normally. So I have my setting for PosgreSQL at Trust which usually means I don't need to provide extra information but with GDAL I do.

To solve the problem I simply edited the connection setting by right clicking on the PostgreSQL database in the QGIS browser pane and selecting edit connection.